# header element, height in em not working

Tags: html, css

I expect the header to be 4em.. but it's smaller
why?

My HTML is:

```
    <header id="header">
        <div class="content">
            <h1><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></h1>
        </div>
    </header>
```

My css is:

```
header#header{
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    height: 4em;
}

#header#header .content{
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 4em;
}
#header h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 4em;
    font: bold 1.5em/4em arial;
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://www.impressivewebs.com/understanding-em-units-css/. `em` is based on the `font-size` property. Since you haven't specified a `font-size` for the `header` it will default to `16px` or inherit it from the parent.

Comment: The example below would suggest otherwise, in your case 1em is set to 16 pixels. If you inspect the element, you will see it is 4em or to put it another  way 64px.   https://jsfiddle.net/zm0c6Lo8/

Comment: em is a relative unit. Child's size will inherit from parent's size. You still need to set/increase parent's size

Comment: You are all correct, missed it.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

em unit depends on the parent font size, by default the font size of elements is 16px
so if you put 4em that mean 16*4 = 64px.
you need to choose a bigger number